# Setting a 1 or 2-character text on a JButton 32x32

Tags: java, button, text, jbutton, counter

I want to set the text on a JButton that is size 32x32 but it only shows "...". yeah I know you could see the text if you make the button bigger, but how do you make the text be shown on a 32x32 jbutton? The text is only 1 or 2 digits(characters), it is actually a counter. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The insets are probably crowding out the text...

try

```
button.setMargin(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

edit:  Also, use a smaller font.

edit2: you can also control the insets for all buttons:

```
UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, this is managed directly by the *look'n'feel'* that is used by Java. You could try by [changing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) it to another one to see if there is one with different insets. You could try changing them by setting smaller insects programatically.

A more complex way would be to subclass the `JButton` class and provide a custom drawing implementation but I think you will lose all the other cool effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
As per my idea , its quite simple to making GUI application  easier.I am writing some code below it may help you .

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JFrame frm=new JFrame("Manoj Button Test");
            frm.setVisible(true);
            frm.setSize(500,500);
            Container cnt=frm.getContentPane();
                        //You can add any text to the JButton
            JButton btn=new JButton("Hello Button");
            cnt.add(btn);           

            //2nd type of example 
            JButton btn2=new JButton();
            int number_btntext=4;
            btn2.setText(String.valueOf(number_btntext));
            cnt.add(btn2);


    }


In the above code I have set text to GUI JButton.
```